# Does Feeblemind produce an ongoing magical effect that can be dispelled?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

[*Feeblemind*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/feeblemind) has a duration of instantaneous. However, it also produces an ongoing effect, and the spell's text describes when this effect ends (emphasis added):

> At the end of every 30 days, the creature can repeat its saving throw **against this spell**. If it succeeds on its saving throw, **the spell ends**.
>
> **The spell can also be ended** by *greater restoration*, *heal*, or *wish*.

The fact that the text refers to the *spell* ending, as opposed to just "the effect" or something similar, implies that it produces an ongoing magical spell effect, which can be dispelled using *Dispel Magic*. However, it has also been argued that any effects that persist beyond a spell's stated duration cannot be considered magical (with the classic example being fires started by a *Fireball* spell). Applying this rule to *Feeblemind*, it shouldn't have any ongoing effects since its duration is instantaneous. So, which is it? Are the ongoing effects of *Feeblemind* considered magical and therefore susceptible to effects like *Dispel Magic*, or are are they simply the lingering result of the initial shattering of the creature's intellect and personality?

(Note that the final sentence quoted above does not by itself rule out *Dispel Magic* and other ways of ending the spell. It gives *additional* options for ending the spell, but it doesn't say these are the *only* options.)

Comment: I have been wondering the same thing but with the Arcana Clerics 6th level skill Spell Breaker

Comment: @Alk As was I...see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/146776/will-cleansing-touch-or-spell-breaker-end-feeblemind).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### *Feeblemind* can't be dispelled

The [*feeblemind*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/feeblemind) spell has an instantaneous duration which means specifically:

> The spell harms, heals, creates, or alters a creature or an object in a way that can't be dispelled, because its magic exists only for an instant.
>
> — *Player's Handbook* on Instantaneous duration, p. 203

This is supported by designer intent in a ([now unofficial](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/140221/52137)) [pair](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/729777344148217857) of [tweets](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/848956160333959170) by Jeremy Crawford, and has been addressed in the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#SpecificSpells):

> **Can you use dispel magic on the creations of a spell like animate dead or affect those creations with antimagic field?**
>
> Whenever you wonder whether a spell’s effects can be dispelled or suspended, you need to answer one question: is the spell’s duration instantaneous? If the answer is yes, there is nothing to dispel or suspend. Here’s why: the effects of an instantaneous spell are brought into being by magic, but the effects aren’t sustained by magic. The magic flares for a split second and then vanishes.

(that answer also continues with the examples of *animate dead* and *cure wounds*)

The most likely fix to the ambiguity would to rephrase (or interpret) the later clauses to 'the spell's effect ends'. The game does not always make a distinction between the two terms. Specifically the spell [*Leomund's secret chest*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/leomunds-secret-chest) (in the SRD as [*secret chest*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/secret-chest)) is also instantaneous and includes the paragraph (emphasis mine):

> After 60 days, there is a cumulative 5 percent chance per day that the **spell's effect** ends. This effect ends if you cast this spell again, if the smaller replica chest is destroyed, or if you choose to end **the spell** as an action. [...]
>
> — *Player's Handbook*, p. 254

Here both ending the spell's effect and ending the spell are used to describe the same thing, which is similar to that of *feeblemind*. Likely if the effect of *feeblemind* was to be dispellable it's duration would have been listed as 'Until Dispelled' or something similar, like with [*transmute rock*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/transmute-rock) or [*magic jar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-jar).

Comment: I think the fact that the rules don't consistently distinguish between "spell" and "spell effect" is an important and relevant point.

Comment: @RyanThompson: yeah, "effect ends" would have been much better wording.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes, Dispel Magic works (but only after a successful Spellcasting Ability Check)

You've quoted the relevant parts of the spell: a creature that succeeds on their latent saving throw "ends the spell". That wouldn't be possible if the effect weren't being maintained by an active "Spell Effect"; therefore, the ongoing effect of *Feeblemind* must constitute a Spell Effect, dispellable by *Dispel Magic*. This constitutes a "Specific beats General" exception to the normal rule that Instantaneous Spells must not be dispellable.

The catch, of course, is that *Feeblemind*, as an 8th level spell, is difficult to remove. Someone trying to dispel it using *Dispel Magic* would have to either cast *Dispel Magic* as an 8th level spell, or else pass the Spellcasting Ability check to dispel it; and at a DC of 18, that can be difficult, considering that "Spellcasting Ability check"s don't use the caster's proficiency modifier, and because *Dispel Magic* does not have material components, certain kinds of magic items (like a +1 Wand, used as an Arcane Focus) would not benefit this check.

<sub>Other kinds of magic items might count though; check the item description to find out whether it requires that it be actively used as a focus to confer the benefits or not.</sub>

This is why the alternate methods of removing the spell, like *Heal*, *Greater Restoration*, or *Wish*, are a major benefit: they're guaranteed to successfully remove the effect without needing to pass a check, making them under certain circumstances (especially time-constrained circumstances or spell-slot constrained circumstances) much better options for removing this kind of effect. If these options were not listed, then it would be far more difficult to remove this effect.

## The *Intent* is that only the three spells listed are valid to remove the effect

> The intent is that feeblemind can be ended only by the methods specified in the spell. #DnD
>
> —**Jeremy Crawford**, Twitter, [2017-04-03@3:51PM EDT](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/848956160333959170?s=19)

So at least from the informal perspective of the Lead Rules Designer, the spell *should* only be removable by those three spells listed above.

I maintain, however, from a Rules-as-Written perspective, that because the spell describes the successful saving throw as ending the spell, it is therefore the case that until errata or a Sage Advice compendium comes out that specifically adjudicates against this, *Dispel Magic* (and other effects that "end active spells") are valid against *Feeblemind*.