# Will the paladin's Cleansing Touch or the Arcana cleric's Spell Breaker feature end the Feeblemind spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, cleric, paladin

The *[Feeblemind](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/feeblemind)* spell provides a list of things that can end the spell, but it may or may not be exhaustive.

Can the effects of the spell be ended by the Paladin's Cleansing Touch feature or the Arcana Cleric's Spell Breaker feature?

Comment: Related on [Does feeblemind produce an ongoing magical effect that can be dispelled?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/146765/does-feeblemind-produce-an-ongoing-magical-effect-that-can-be-dispelled)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## No.  The spell, [*feeblemind*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/feeblemind), ends instantly after it is cast.

The duration of *feeblemind* is instantaneous.  So the spell itself ends as soon as it is cast.  The **effects** of the spell endure after the spell itself.

### Cleansing Touch

[Cleansing Touch](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#CleansingTouch) ends a spell, not the effects of a spell.  As such, Cleansing Touch cannot end the effects of *feeblemind*.

### Spell Breaker

The relevant passage from the Spell Breaker class feature of the [Arcana Domain cleric](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#ArcanaDomain) (SCAG, p. 126) is:

> ... you can also end one spell of your choice on that creature.

Since *feeblemind* ends instantaneously, there is not an ongoing spell for Spell Breaker to end.  The ongoing effect of the spell does not mean that the spell is on going.

Comment: Feeblemind states after 30 day you get a save against the “spell” not the effects of the spell. Because it is instantaneous we have to believe the language “spell” and “spell effects” mean the same thing (sometimes). So with that maybe Cleansing Touch/Spell Breaker end spells/spell effects.

Comment: @Alk you raise a good point, which is discussed in more detail in [this answer to "Does Feeblemind produce an ongoing magical effect that can be dispelled?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/146778/42959).